# Обращение к элементу в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

В jQuery обращение к элементу происходит с помощью `$('#id').onEventName()= {}` или `$('.class').onEventName()= {}`, а как происходит обращение к элементу в JavaScript?

Comment: Запомните Все не декларация функции () - это ее вызов. Так вот $('#id').onEventName() это вызов функции и присвоить значение результату работы функции не получится. У вас идет запрос $('#id') почитайте jquery

Comment: Как интересно, изучать жквери, не разобравшись с основами...

Answer (score 4):

`document.querySelector('.class').addEventListener(ev, cb, {});`

[Поиск элемента](https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom) и [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Также для прослушивания событий можно использовать `onclick(ev)`, `onmouseenter(ev)` и тд.

Answer (score 2):

Прочитайте про [селекторы](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) JQuery

[пример](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_id.asp)

Выберите элемент с **идентификатором** intro:

$("#intro")

[пример](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_class.asp)

Выделите все элементы с **классом** "intro":

$(".intro")

А нативно на JS можно обратиться

[document.getElementById(Id)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

[document.getElementsByClassName(class)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: вопрос был про нативный эквивалент

Comment: @teran добавил в ответ

Answer (score 2):

Проблема (или, преимущество) в том, что jQuery оставляет все необходимые циклы за кулисами. Что с одним элементом, что с нескольким - зачастую код выглядит одинаково. А на стандартном JS нужно делать переборы "вручную".

В JS есть:

- `document.querySelector(".class")` - возвращает первый соответствующий элемент на странице, или `null`, если ничего не найдет.

  * на jQuery, обращение к первому элементу: `$(".class").eq(0)`
- `document.querySelectorAll(".class")` - всегда возвращает `NodeList` коллекцию всех найденных элементов. К каждому элементу из коллекции можно обращаться через его номер. Если элементов не найдено, вернет коллекцию нулевой длины (`length: 0`)

И `querySelector`-ы, и jQuery-функция `$()` помимо классов, поддерживают любой стандартный [CSS-селектор](https://webref.ru/css#selectors)

```js
$("div").addClass("blue");


let div = document.querySelectorAll("div");
for (let i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
  div[i].classList.add("yellow");
}
// div[0].classList.add("yellow"); // первый
// div[1].classList.add("yellow"); // второй...
// ...


document.querySelector("div").style.backgroundColor = "#2ad";
// обращение к первому элементу
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 4px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #169;
}
.yellow {
  color: #fd0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```